# Add a custom user control multiple times to a listbox

Tags: c#, listbox

I have a custom control with a button and a couple of fields. I'm trying to display the control in a list box multiple times depending on some data.
but the control only displays once in the listbox.

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    string[] printers = { "1", "2", "3" };

    foreach(string value in printers)
    {
      Pmonitor pmonitor_control = new Pmonitor();
      listBox1.Controls.Add(pmonitor_control);

    }



}
```

Comment: What is your intention of doing this? If you want a list of controls, this is not the way to do it. Control.Controls is a collection used mainly by container controls, which listbox is not.

Comment: Can you create a different class that wraps `Pmonitor` and are not equal to each other only to themselves?

Comment: @EugeneSh.Yes I want to add a list of my usercontrol. what other way do you suggest?

Comment: if I use listbox1.items.add(pmonitor_control);
it shows 3 lines in the listbox but doenst display the usercontrol.

Comment: Add them to a FlowLayoutPanel instead?...

Comment: @Jean-paulTillapaugh If you describe exactly what you want to get, maybe we'll come up with a suggestion. But if it is just a controls, that you want to have on some scrollable thing, use scrollable container, such as panel.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a collection( List) of your control and bind the collection to the ListBox.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the help but I think I've found my answer. Thanks Idle_mind for pointing me in the right direction.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/windows/en-US/9721308d-52f8-430b-aad6-69661c18d5f1/usercontrol-as-a-listviewitem